# Facade not found by AliasLoader in Laravel

Tags: laravel, facade

I added a custom facade to my 'config/app.php' in my laravel project under 'aliases'

`'GeoLocation' => '\App\Facades\GeoLocation',`

The folder of the custom class is in `'app/Facades/GeoLocation.php'` and the service provider in `'app/Providers/GeoLocationServiceProvider.php'`

How do I need to state the correct alias in the app.php to be able to load the Facade correctly? The error message is:

`ErrorException in AliasLoader.php line 63:
Class 'Facades\GeoLocation' not found`

This is my facade:

```
<?php namespace App\Facades;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class GeoLocation extends Facade {
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'geolocation'; }
}
```

Could it be that the return value of my service provider is incorrect?

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class GeoLocationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {

        \App::bind('geolocation', function()
        {
            return new GeoLocation;
        });
    }
}
```

For a test I created another service provider called custom function:

```
<?php namespace App\Helpers;

class CustomFunction {
    //Generate random float between -1 and 1
    function f_rand($min = 0, $max = 1, $mul = 1000000) {
        if ($min>$max) return false;
        return mt_rand($min*$mul, $max*$mul) / $mul;
    }

    function test() {
        echo "OK";
    }
}

<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CustomFunctionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {

        \App::bind('customfunctions', function()
        {
            return new CustomFunction;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: change your namespace to App\Facades\GeoLocation and update your app.php accordingly, because your Facades\ namespace is not in your composer autoload coverage

Comment: Sorry to ask.. Where do I need to change the namespace?

Comment: you have to make changes to the file app/Facades/GeoLocation.php

Comment: can we quickly chat? :)

Comment: I am sorry.. I tried that but it did not work. Let me quickly edit my question

Comment: Is this the correct way? I tried it but still no result. I really have issues still with namespaces I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest way is to change the namespace to the file app/Facades/GeoLocation.php' to `App\Facades`;

then update aliase registration to

```
'GeoLocation' => 'App\Facades\GeoLocation',
```

Comment: I just did that and get this feedback:
`FatalErrorException in TestController.php line 17:
Class 'Facades\GeoLocation' not found`

Comment: you need to change the namespace to the file CustomFunction as well,

Comment: Did that.. still the same message

Comment: did you make changes to app.php
to register your facades this way ?

`'GeoLocation' => 'App\Facades\GeoLocation',`

Comment: Yes... `'GeoLocation' => 'App\Facades\GeoLocation',
        'CustomFunction' => 'App\Facades\CustomFunction',`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73856/discussion-between-terry-low-and-isarfaktor).